# Is there a tool that can read and write to disk at constant throughput?

Tags: io, benchmark

I'm looking for a tool that can read and write data at a constant target throughput, say 3Mb/s, rather than pushing the I/O system to its limits. I then intend to monitor various metrics whilst this fairly constant I/O activity is happening. I've looked at tools like `stress` and `fio` but it seems like they're more geared towards maximum throughput. Any suggestions for tools that can do something like this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the `--rate` option to `fio` which seems to do what I want:

```
rate=int[,int][,int]

Cap the bandwidth used by this job. The number is in bytes/sec, the normal suffix
rules apply. Comma-separated values may be specified for reads, writes, and trims
as described in blocksize.

For example, using rate=1m,500k would limit reads to 1MiB/sec and writes to
500KiB/sec. Capping only reads or writes can be done with rate=,500k or
rate=500k, where the former will only limit writes (to 500KiB/sec) and the latter
will only limit reads.
```

https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_man.html#cmdoption-arg-rate

Answer (score 2):

`pv -L` should be able to cover.

Comment: Maybe piped to `dd obs=4k oflag=dsync > out` to force a flush to disk every 4KiB (assuming GNU du). Otherwise how data is written to disk is up to the I/O scheduler (though *on average*, it will be as specified with `pv -L`).